# Why isn't my text wrapping around a floated element?

Tags: html, css

I'm picking up HTML again (I know the language but it's been a while since I've used it) and I'm attempting to make a webpage that teaches the user a bit about how coding languages work. I want to add a text box off to the side of the page as a sort of note about the difference between HTML's being a markup language, compared to other languages.

However, in my CSS file, the `float` property is not displaying correctly, and I'm not sure why:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", "Times New Roman";
  background: black;
  color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
}

.note {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Functions</h1>
<p>C-derived languages usually have a few tricks in common, and there are some things present in virtually every language.</p>
<div>
  <p class="note">If you look at the HTML that made this page, you'll notice that it doesn't include almost anything described below, and in fact looks much, much different. This is because HTML is a <b>markup language</b>, not a programming language; there is a difference.
    In HTML, elements are written with angle brackets (for example, <span>&lt;p&gt;</span> for a paragraph), but in most other <i>programming languages</i>, code simply floats in the file, so-to-speak. Take a look at the functions below to see the contrasts.</p>
</div>
<p>Different languages call them different things, but there is a name for a runnable set of code. JavaScript calls it a function; C# calls it a method - but for the most part they mean the same thing. For this, they will be called functions. Functions are simply a bunch of code that is run together, along with optional arguments, which are inputtable variables. </p>
```

Don't worry about what the text actually says; I just want to know why the text is not wrapping around the box.

Comment: What text do you expect to wrap around the `p.note` box?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. What are you expecting to happen? You probably want to give the note class a width.

Comment: Assign some width to your `.note` to see float effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's floating, but it's just full width because you have no width assigned to it, so it appears not to be floating.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", "Times New Roman";
  background: black;
  color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
}

.note {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Functions</h1>
<p>C-derived languages usually have a few tricks in common, and there are some things present in virtually every language.</p>
<div>
  <p class="note">If you look at the HTML that made this page, you'll notice that it doesn't include almost anything described below, and in fact looks much, much different. This is because HTML is a <b>markup language</b>, not a programming language; there is a difference.
    In HTML, elements are written with angle brackets (for example, <span>&lt;p&gt;</span> for a paragraph), but in most other <i>programming languages</i>, code simply floats in the file, so-to-speak. Take a look at the functions below to see the contrasts.</p>
</div>
<p>Different languages call them different things, but there is a name for a runnable set of code. JavaScript calls it a function; C# calls it a method - but for the most part they mean the same thing. For this, they will be called functions. Functions are simply a bunch of code that is run together, along with optional arguments, which are inputtable variables. </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like j08691 said in his comment, the `p.note` element is filling the full width of its div parent, as `<p>` elements do naturally. Give the `<p>` a width, and the other text will wrap around it.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", "Times New Roman";
  background: black;
  color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
}

.note {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Functions</h1>
<p>C-derived languages usually have a few tricks in common, and there are some things present in virtually every language.</p>
<div>
  <p class="note">If you look at the HTML that made this page, you'll notice that it doesn't include almost anything described below, and in fact looks much, much different. This is because HTML is a <b>markup language</b>, not a programming language; there is a difference.
    In HTML, elements are written with angle brackets (for example, <span>&lt;p&gt;</span> for a paragraph), but in most other <i>programming languages</i>, code simply floats in the file, so-to-speak. Take a look at the functions below to see the contrasts.</p>
</div>
<p>Different languages call them different things, but there is a name for a runnable set of code. JavaScript calls it a function; C# calls it a method - but for the most part they mean the same thing. For this, they will be called functions. Functions are simply a bunch of code that is run together, along with optional arguments, which are inputtable variables. </p>
```